# "Key is not unique for value ''" thrown by read_csv

Tags: ansible

My playbook used to be able to run successfully without any issues.
But recently, I ran the playbook again (without changing anything) and got this error:

```
TASK [read_csv] *****************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Key 'username' is not unique for value ''"}
```

This is the playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Read User
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - read_csv:
      path: opt/ansible.csv
      key: username
      fieldnames: username,usergroups,ipaddress,lastlogindate
      delimiter: ','
    register: usersdata
```

This is an example of the CSV file that I am using:

| Username | User_groups | IP Address | Last Login Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | A | 192.34.50.183 | 12/4/2021 |
| Blizz | B | 192.34.50.145 | 3/8/2021 |

What is value ''? And why is using 'username' as the key now wrong?

===============================================================

**Update:**

I tried the playbook suggested by Vladimir Botka below, and it was able to run successfully.

```
PLAY [Read User] ***************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [read_csv] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "usersdata.dict": {}
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "usersdata.list": [
        {
            "IP Address": "192.169.60.220 - XXX.XXX.60.254",
            "Last Login Date": "30-Jul-21",
            "User_groups": "B",
            "Username": "Vijay"
        },
        {
            "IP Address": "XXX.XXX.60.146 - XXX.XXX.60.147",
            "Last Login Date": "1-Jan-21",
            "User_groups": "ecquaria",
            "Username": "wangjcecquaria"
        },
…

TASK [read_csv] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "usersdata.dict": {
        "Kyawryobi": {
            "IP Address": "XXX.XXX.60.184 - XXX.XXX.60.185",
            "Last Login Date": "28-Jul-21",
            "User_groups": "Ryobi",
            "Username": "Kyawryobi"
        },
        "Nikhil": {
            "IP Address": "XXX.XXX.60.1 - XXX.XXX.60.80",
            "Last Login Date": "30-Jul-21",
            "User_groups": "A",
            "Username": "Joshua"
        },
        "Vijay": {
   …
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "usersdata.list": []
}

TASK [read_csv] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "usersdata.dict": {}
}
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "usersdata.list": [
        {
            "ipaddress": "IP Address",
            "lastlogindate": "Last Login Date",
            "usergroups": "User_groups",
            "username": "Username"
        },
        {
            "ipaddress": "192.169.60.220 - XXX.XXX.60.254",
            "lastlogindate": "30-Jul-21",
            "usergroups": "A",
            "username": "Joshua"
        },
        {
…

TASK [read_csv] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "usersdata.dict": {
        "Kyawryobi": {
            "ipaddress": "XXX.XXX.60.184 - XXX.XXX.60.185",
            "lastlogindate": "28-Jul-21",
            "usergroups": "Ryobi",
            "username": "Kyawryobi"
        },
        "Nikhil": {
            "ipaddress": "XXX.XXX.60.1 - XXX.XXX.60.80",
            "lastlogindate": "30-Jul-21",
            "usergroups": "A",
            "username": "Joshua"
        },
        "Username": {
…

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "usersdata.list": []
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=13   changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Next, I tried running my playbook again without changing anything else in the settings or playbook and there is no more error.

```
PLAY [Read User] ***************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [read_csv] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************

localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I think the error, "Key is not unique for value ''", might be the result of a bug, and running a playbook that triggers ansible to output a dictionary and list using the usersdata variable might have resolved it. I have checked and there is nothing wrong with the data in my CSV. There are no missing values in the 'Username' column, neither do I have the word 'username' duplicated anywhere else.

Comment: What it means is, somewhere in your CSV, you have data filled for other fields than `username` and nothing filled in `username`, on multiple rows, and that's not something the CSV module can let you do, as you have stated that `username` is an _unique_ key.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I have checked again, I do not have any empty cells in my CSV, and the values in my username column are all various usernames.

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem. Run the example playbook below and report issues if any. Otherwise, something must be missing from your story.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε that comment helped me to resolve my issue at least. Some of the rows in my csv had no values assigned in the columns and Ansible was throwing this cryptic error message due to that. Deleting the rows with missing data or filling in the missing data helped Ansible to run and stop throwing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the module [*community.general.read_csv*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/read_csv_module.html#community-general-read-csv-module-read-a-csv-file) takes the first line of a file as a header. You can declare [*fieldnames*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/read_csv_module.html#parameter-fieldnames) if the header is missing. Quoting:

> A list of field names for every column. This is needed if the CSV does not have a header.

Given the file

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/ansible.csv 
Username,User_groups,IP Address,Last Login Date
Apple,A,192.34.50.183,12/4/2021
Blizz,B,192.34.50.145,3/8/2021
```

1. You don't have to declare *fieldnames* because the first line is the header

```yaml
    - read_csv:
        path: /tmp/ansible.csv
      register: usersdata
```

gives (see the notes below on the output dictionary vs. list)

```yaml
  usersdata.list:
  - IP Address: 192.34.50.183
    Last Login Date: 12/4/2021
    User_groups: A
    Username: Apple
  - IP Address: 192.34.50.145
    Last Login Date: 3/8/2021
    User_groups: B
    Username: Blizz
```

2. If you do declare *fieldnames* all lines are treated as data

```yaml
    - read_csv:
        path: /tmp/ansible.csv
        fieldnames: username,usergroups,ipaddress,lastlogindate
      register: usersdata
```

gives the list with renamed fields including an additional item of the original header

```yaml
  usersdata.list:
  - ipaddress: IP Address
    lastlogindate: Last Login Date
    usergroups: User_groups
    username: Username
  - ipaddress: 192.34.50.183
    lastlogindate: 12/4/2021
    usergroups: A
    username: Apple
  - ipaddress: 192.34.50.145
    lastlogindate: 3/8/2021
    usergroups: B
    username: Blizz
```

3. If you declare a *key* in addition to the *fieldnames*

```yaml
    - read_csv:
        path: /tmp/ansible.csv
        key: username
        fieldnames: username,usergroups,ipaddress,lastlogindate
      register: usersdata
```

you get the dictionary of this key's values

```yaml
  usersdata.dict:
    Apple:
      ipaddress: 192.34.50.183
      lastlogindate: 12/4/2021
      usergroups: A
      username: Apple
    Blizz:
      ipaddress: 192.34.50.145
      lastlogindate: 3/8/2021
      usergroups: B
      username: Blizz
    Username:
      ipaddress: IP Address
      lastlogindate: Last Login Date
      usergroups: User_groups
      username: Username
```

---

**Notes**

1. The output depends on the parameter [*key*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/read_csv_module.html#parameter-key).

a) Without a *key*

```yaml
    - read_csv:
        path: /tmp/ansible.csv
      register: usersdata
    - debug:
        var: usersdata.dict
    - debug:
        var: usersdata.list
```

you get an empty dictionary and a list of the lines

```yaml
  usersdata.dict: {}

  usersdata.list:
  - IP Address: 192.34.50.183
    Last Login Date: 12/4/2021
    User_groups: A
    Username: Apple
  - IP Address: 192.34.50.145
    Last Login Date: 3/8/2021
    User_groups: B
    Username: Blizz
```

b) If you specify a key (it's case-sensitive)

```yaml
    - read_csv:
        path: /tmp/ansible.csv
        key: Username
      register: usersdata
```

you get a dictionary of this key's values and an empty list

```yaml
  usersdata.dict:
    Apple:
      IP Address: 192.34.50.183
      Last Login Date: 12/4/2021
      User_groups: A
      Username: Apple
    Blizz:
      IP Address: 192.34.50.145
      Last Login Date: 3/8/2021
      User_groups: B
      Username: Blizz

  usersdata.list: []
```

---

2. Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - read_csv:
        path: /tmp/ansible.csv
      register: usersdata
    - debug:
        var: usersdata.dict
    - debug:
        var: usersdata.list

    - read_csv:
        path: /tmp/ansible.csv
        key: Username
      register: usersdata
    - debug:
        var: usersdata.dict
    - debug:
        var: usersdata.list

    - read_csv:
        path: /tmp/ansible.csv
        fieldnames: username,usergroups,ipaddress,lastlogindate
      register: usersdata
    - debug:
        var: usersdata.dict
    - debug:
        var: usersdata.list

    - read_csv:
        path: /tmp/ansible.csv
        key: username
        fieldnames: username,usergroups,ipaddress,lastlogindate
      register: usersdata
    - debug:
        var: usersdata.dict
    - debug:
        var: usersdata.list
```

Comment: I ran your playbook, for tasks which contained a key, usersdata.dict would output each row of data from the CSV file tagged to the key (username). For tasks which do not contain a key, usersdata.list would be the variable that outputs the data row by row as listed in the CSV file. After I ran your playbook, I ran mine, and the job was able to run successfully. I think there was some bug (I did not change anything in the playbook or CSV file) and running your playbook helped to reset those buggy settings I guess. Thank you.

Comment: You should close the question. If we don't know what's the problem there is no point in keeping it.